# AttributeError: type object 'Post' has no attribute 'query'

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, attributeerror

I followed Corey Schafer's flask tutorial to build a social media website. However, when I got to the Create a post stage, I encountered "AttributeError: type object 'Post' has no attribute 'query'" but I don't understand why and Corey didn't encounter this problem in the video... I am really new to this and I have no idea what had gone wrong, any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question.

Comment: Your line 10 of `route.py` from the traceback is different from the code you gave us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are not using the `Post(db.Model)` in your `model.py` that does have the `query` method but your program is using the `Post(FlaskForm)` from `form.py`. As they have the same name your imports are overriding each other:

```py
# simplified
from sm.model import Post
from sm.forms import Post
```

Try explicitly naming them `PostModel` and `PostForm` for easier clarification between the two.

(You will notice that this is exactly what is done in [Corey Schafers code snippets](https://github.com/CoreyMSchafer/code_snippets/blob/3e23f3ecc7f6ff0a8a1b55df297673d0618e9137/Python/Flask_Blog/08-Posts/flaskblog/forms.py#L59) )